# yum group install will mandatory and default packages. How to install the optional packages?

Tags: linux, software-installation

`yum group info <name of group>` lists the mandatory, default and optional packages. Yet, when trying to install the group using `yum group install <group>`, it only installs mandatory and default packages. How to install the optional packages as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `--with-optional` to include the optional packages on RHEL/CentOS 8 and 9.